# Can I call a function of other unrelated class

Tags: c++

I am not sure if it is allowed but I want to give it a try.
I have 2 classes as below which are unrelated and I want to call the function b_Method() of class B in Class A and I am interested only what boolean value it returns.

```
class A
{
Public:
bool a_Method()
{
B *obj = new B();       
bool varBool= obj->b_Method();
return varbool;
}      
}

class B
{
public:
bool b_Method()
{
"does something"
return varBool;
}
}
```

I tried to call b_Method() in class A as other option would be exactly replicate all the code of b_Method() in a_Method(), but I got following compiler errors.

```
: error C2065:'A' : undeclared identifier
: error C2065: 'obj' : undeclared identifier
: error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'A'
: error C2228: left of '->b_Method' must have class/struct/union
        type is ''unknown-type''
```

Comment: you should predeclare class B before using it in class A

Comment: Thanks, I just defined the method in Class A instead of Class B as their definitions were essentially same and called it in class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the method *before* you call it.

Also, if the method is `static` (you can mark it static if it doesn't use any of `B`'s instance variables), you can simply call `B::b_Method()` from anywhere and it will run. No need to make an instance.

Finally, don't forget to `delete` your instances! Or use

```
B obj;
bool varBool= obj.b_Method();
return varbool;
```

instead (which doesn't allocate dynamic memory, so no need to `delete`)

Answer (score 0):

```
class B
{
public:
    bool b_Method()
    {
        return true;
    }
}; 
class A
{
public:
    bool a_Method()
    {
        B *obj = new B();       
        bool varBool= obj->b_Method();
        return varBool;
    }      
};
```